# HTTP Status 404 Spring rest The requested resource is not available

Tags: spring, rest, http-status-code-404, path-variables

I am using spring 3.2.2.RELEASE and have a problem on sending request to server :

```
http://asdsda:8080/spr-mvc-hib/user/userHizmet.html?userId=19
```

HTTP Status 404 The requested resource is not available.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userHizmet/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView userHizmet(@PathVariable String userId)
{
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("userte");
```

where i called :

```
success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        window.location.href="${pageContext. request. contextPath}/user/userHizmet.html?userId="+data;
                    },
```

dispatcher :

```
Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
    servlet.addMapping("/");
```

Comment: Please check out the URL. Your URL seems wrong.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/spr-mvc-hib/user/userHizmet.html?userId=19 where is the problem ? normally I used in several places without parameter with ?, I think my dispatcher or pathvariable is not correct,doesnt it?

Comment: Update your URL with servlet (userHizmet.html) .

Comment: what do you mean by update ? what should I use?
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/user")
public class UserControllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
localhost:8080/spr-mvc-hib/user/userHizmet.html?userId=19
```

removing `.html` and using `requestparam` solved my problem